# Implementing Miller-Rabin in C

Tags: c, algorithm, primes, primality-test

I'm trying to implement the [Miller-Rabin primality test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test) in C99, but I'm coming across some problems getting it to work. I crafted a small test-set to verify whether or not the implementation works, here's how I'm checking for primes

```
int main() {
    int foo[11] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 28, 73, 125, 991, 1000};
    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
        printf("%s; ", isprime(foo[i], 5000) ? "Yes" : "No");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

From the numbers listed, the expected output would be

> No; No; Yes; Yes; No; Yes; No; Yes; No; Yes; No;

However, as implemented , the output I get is the following:

> No; No; Yes; Yes; No; Yes; No; No; No; No; No;

Here's how I wrote the algorithm

```
int randint (int low, int up){
    return rand() % (++up - low)+low;
}

int modpow(int a, int b, int m) {
    int c = 1;
    while (b) {
        if (b & 1) {
            c *= a;
        }
        b >>= 1;
        a *= a;
    }
    return c % m;
}

bool witness(int a, int s, int d, int n) {
    int x = modpow(a,d,n);
    if(x == 1) return true;
    for(int i = 0; i< s-1; i++){
        if(x == n-1) return true;
        x = modpow(x,2,n);
    }
    return (x == n- 1);
}

bool isprime(int x, int j) {
    if (x == 2) {
        return true;
    }
    if (!(x & 1) || x <= 1) {
        return false;
    }
    int a = 0;
    int s = 0;
    int d = x - 1;

    while (!d&1){
        d >>=1;
        s+=1;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < j; i++){
        a = randint(2, x-1);
        if(!witness(a,s,d,x)){
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Why is the test failing for "large" primes, but working for very small ones? How may I fix this?

Comment: Possibly because your `modpow()` overflows computing `a^b` *before* reducing modulo-`m`.  You'll need to reduce `a` and `c` as you go.  If you write some tests for `modpow()`, you'll have greater confidence in it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With Visual Studio 2015 Community edition I found two problems. First the line:

```
while (!d&1){
```

needs to be:

```
while (!(d&1)){
```

Secondly, as mentioned in the comments your modpow function is overflowing. Try:

```
int modpow(int a, int d, int m) {
    int c = a;
    for (int i = 1; i < d; i++)
        c = (c*a) % m;
    return c % m;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are problems in your `modpow()` function.  You probably want to use unsigned types for the arguments and the result (what would a negative `m` mean, anyway?)  Secondly, it overflows because it tries to compute `a^b` before reducing it modulo-`m`. You need to reduce `a` and `c` as you go.

The best way to deal with this is to write some tests:

```
unsigned modpow(unsigned a, unsigned b, unsigned m) {
    unsigned c = 1;
    while (b) {
        if (b & 1) {
            c *= a;
        }
        b >>= 1;
        a *= a;
    }
    return c % m;
}

#include <stdio.h>
unsigned test(unsigned a, unsigned b, unsigned m, unsigned expected)
{
    unsigned actual = modpow(a, b, m);
    if (actual == expected)
        return 0;
    printf("modpow(%u, %u, %u) returned %u; expected %u\n",
           a, b, m, actual, expected);
    return 1;
}


int main()
{
    return test(0, 0, 2, 1)
        +  test(1005, 16, 100, 25)
        ;
}
```

The first test passes (but raises a question - what result do you want when `m < 2`?); the second one fails:

> modpow(1005, 16, 100) returned 49; expected 25

Let's modify `modpow()` to reduce the result at each step:

```
unsigned modpow(unsigned a, unsigned b, unsigned m) {
    unsigned c = 1;
    while (b) {
        if (b & 1) {
            c *= a;
            c %= m;
        }
        b >>= 1;
        a *= a;
        a %= m;
    }
    return c;
}
```

It now passes!  We can make another failing test:

```
int main()
{
    return test(0, 0, 2, 1)
        +  test(1005, 16, 100, 25)
        +  test(100000005, 16, 1000000000, 587890625)
        ;
}
```

> modpow(100000005, 16, 1000000000) returned 919214529; expected 587890625

Now we need to calculate the multiplication using a larger type:

```
unsigned modpow(unsigned a, unsigned b, unsigned m) {
    unsigned long long c = 1;
    while (b) {
        if (b & 1) {
            c = (unsigned long long)c * a % m;
        }
        b >>= 1;
        a = (unsigned long long)a * a % m;
    }
    return c;
}
```

Once we have sufficient confidence in the `modpow()` function, we can debug the rest of the algorithm.

---

Note that if your integer sizes are different to mine, you'll need to use different values in the tests to replicate the results.  I chose large numbers ending in `005` because we know the last two digits are invariant `25` regardless of the power.  You might find that `dc -e '???|p'` helps in generating test cases (supply the three arguments on its stdin, and it will print the expected value).